# Is there any advantage to using memoization in my Rails controller show method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, memoization

I'm using Rails 5.1.  I'm wondering if there's any advantage to using memoization in my controllers.  For example, I have the below show method ...

```
class PartsController < BaseController

  def show
    @part = Part.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I could make this

```
  def show
    @part ||= Part.find(params[:id])
  end
```

but since a new instance of a controller is created by a request (keep me honest on that assertion), it doesn't seem like my "@part" would ever get reused.  Am I wrong?  Should I be using memoization th improve performance here?

Comment: No need. Every request triggers a new instance of the controller. Then all instance variables from the controller instance are copied over to an instance of ActionView. The view is then rendered and the instance vars can be garbo collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no benefit here. You could maybe write tests for it in a way so only one instance of a controller class is used but I've never seen anybody doing this for a controller class - probably because it's not how they are used in real life.